# What is datatype of pcollection in apache beam for python version?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-beam, dataflow

I have read many tutorials, and they have explained that output of transform is a Pcollection in apache Beam.
Can anyone explain me, exactly how a Pcollection is stored, what datatype it return if we are applying any transformations.
Is it a python dictionary,tuple,list?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Beam executes pipelines in a *deferred* fashion. This means that you can't access the elements of a PCollection as you build your pipeline - because the PCollection has not been computed:

```
p = beam.Pipeline(runner='....')
input_pcollection = p | ReadFromText(...)

result_pcollection = input_pcollection | beam.Filter(...) | beam.Combine(...)
```

At this point, you've only told Beam which operations it **should execute
in the future** - but these operations **have not been executed yet**.

To actually compute the PCollections, you must:

```
p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

To actually inspect PCollections, try running interactively in Jupyter or Collab notebooks: https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/notebooks/get-started/try-apache-beam-py.ipynb